# Compare defined expressions as text

Tags: c, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor

Say I have a set of defines arranged this way:

```
#define Var0       ((uint32_t)0x00001)
#define Var1       ((uint32_t)0x00002)
#define Var2       ((uint32_t)0x00004)
```

and later in the code I have this:

```
#define CurrVar   Var1
```

When I attempt to compare:

```
#if (CurrVar != Var1)
   #error "CurrVar" has to be "Var1" for this code to work
#endif
```

I get:

```
error: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression
```

I cannot change values of VarX since those are part of a library, but I need to make sure that a proper value is used in the code at compile time.

**Is there a way to compare those expressions?
Even if it will be compared as text, like this:**

```
"((uint32_t)0x00002)" <> "((uint32_t)0x00002)"
or
"Var1" <> "Var1"
etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `_Static_assert`, which is in standard C from 2011 on:

```
_Static_assert(CurrVar == Var1, "CurrVar is not equal to Var1.");
```

If you must use a pre-2011 implementation of C, a common kludge is to declare an array type with an expression that is negative if an assertion fails, causing the compiler to complain about the array size:

```
typedef char CurrVarIsNotEqualToVar1[CurrVar == Var1 ? 1 : -1];
```

Comment: Static assert worked perfectly, thanks! Also, I like the trick with negative array size.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anything C related in such operations. Preprocessor does not understand casts and it does not compare strings.

https://godbolt.org/z/X2xuPa

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define V1 1
#define V2 2
#define V3 3

#define CV V1


#if CV==V1
void foo(void)
{
    printf("V1\n");
}
#else
void foo(void)
{
    printf("not V1\n");
}
#endif

int main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```